# Html2pdf.js result is blank PDF in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html2pdf

I have a vue component and I want to convert this component to PDF file. I used html2pdf.js package but the result is a blank PDF with 3 pages. How can I make it work?

```
<template>
    <div>

      <div ref="document">

        <h2> hello</h2>

      </div>
 <button class="btn btn-success text-center" @click="createPDF">  دریافت فایل pdf</button>

    </div>


</template>

<script>


import html2pdf from 'html2pdf.js'

export default {

    data(){
      return{
      }
    },
    props : ['result'] , 
    watch: {
    },
   methods: {
        createPDF () {
    html2pdf(this.$refs.document, {
                    margin: 1,
                    filename: 'document.pdf',
                    image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
                    html2canvas: { dpi: 192, letterRendering: true ,  scale: 1 , useCORS: true},
                    jsPDF: {   unit: 'in',  format: 'a4', orientation: 'landscape' }
                })
   }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tested your code, it's work fine and create a PDF with hello text, what version vue are you using? and you can also test  "dom-to-pdf" package

Comment: "vue": "^2.5.17",

Comment: "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.12",

Comment: "html2pdf.js": "^0.9.2",

Comment: "jspdf": "^2.3.0",